# In Corona widget show in simulator but not on device

Tags: android, menu, lua, widget, coronasdk

In simulator widgets are shown just fine, but not on device, some of them are missing.
So I even updated corona and started to migrate from 1.0 to Graphics 2.0 engine, width/height doesn't seem to cause problem too, but i still have this problem.

This is part of code:
menu.lua

```
ExitBtn = widget.newButton{
    defaultFile="images/exit.png",
    overFile="images/exit2.png",
    width=44, height=44,
    onRelease = onExitBtnRelease
}
ExitBtn.anchorX,ExitBtn.anchorY = 0.5, 0.5
ExitBtn.x = display.contentWidth-28
ExitBtn.y = 24+50
InfoBtn = widget.newButton{
    defaultFile="images/info.png",
    overFile="images/info2.png"
    width=46, height=46
    --onRelease = onExitBtnRelease
}
InfoBtn.anchorX,InfoBtn.anchorY = 0.5, 0.5
InfoBtn.x = ExitBtn.x-ExitBtn.width-8
InfoBtn.y = ExitBtn.y+2


group:insert( bg1 )
group:insert( bg2 )
group:insert( background )
group:insert( playBtn )
group:insert( ScoresBtn )
group:insert( HowBtn )
group:insert( ExitBtn )
group:insert( InfoBtn)
```

this is onExitBtnRelease function

```
local function onExitBtnRelease()
    native.requestExit()
    return true
end
```

Menu screen should look like this (link below), but buttons on right top corner are missing(on device).
http://s9.postimg.org/rz1c8nu27/start_screen.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any errors logs ?

With no details, I suspect a problem with your images path : "images/info.png". In the simulator, they are not case sensitive but in the devices, they are.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that it, it was named "Exit.png", i didn't even thought about that.